# Isn't a JQuery $.ajax() _synchronous_ call kind of semantically wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I was trying to make a JSON request for an api key.

Some other code must hold until I receive this key (or until I get a timeout error), and since I didn't want to use a callback I thought that it could be a nice case to use synchronous request.

Now I was using jQuery so I ended up writing `"async: false"` in the `$.ajax(){}` call.
But then I realized that I was using a method called `$.ajax()` to make a blocking http request.
How can this be correct? Does jQuery support `"async: false"` just for code practicality purposes (= benefiting of the code consistency given by using `$.ajax()` method in both cases) ?

Wouldn't it be more semantically correct to rewrite the request with a simple `XMLhttpRequest` method set to synchronous mode like this?:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url, false); 
req.send(null);
if(req.status == 200) {  alert(req.responseText); };
```

Comment: There's no semantic difference between doing `async: false` in jQuery and doing `req.open('GET', url, false);` directly. They're doing the same thing, so I'm just not sure what you're asking.

Comment: The semantic difference is in the fact that the JQuery method is called "$.ajax" for asynchronous javascript and xml

Comment: So you're asking about the *naming* semantics only? That's a matter of opinion. AJAX is a non-official term that existed before jQuery did. They presumably adopted the term because of its popularity.

Comment: ...if you're suggesting that a particular letter in the acronym after which a method is named being in semantic conflict with a particular feature of that method is sensible motivation to not use that method, then I must disagree. Surely there are better criteria for deciding what API to use.

Comment: ...and you're in the same boat with `XMLHttpRequest` since neither `XML` nor `Http` are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery library supports the synchronous option because the underlying `XMLHTTPRequest` method also supports it. Naturally the normal way is to make asynchronous requests, but the synchronous option is available for the very few cases when you actually need it.

Regarding using synchronous requests using the `ajax` method where the name contains "a" for asynchronous; the same conflict exists for many other uses of the method. The "x" stands for XML, but it's commonly used for fetching data in other formats, like JSON, HTML or plain text instead of XML. You can even make a JSONP request using the `ajax` method, where the response can never be just XML.

The term AJAX has just come to contain several types of server requests, where only the middle part "Javascript And" is the common denominator.